# Add custom index to entity that inherits from User, which inherits from IdentityUser in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm making ASP.NET MVC Project with user identity. My User class now inherits from IdentityUser:

```
  [Table("Users")]
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Patronymic { get; set; } // Отчество
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } // Дата рождения
    public DateTime? RegisterDate { get; set; } // Actualy it is a dateTime :)
    public bool? Sex { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then I made the Doctor class, which inherits from it:

```
  [Table("Doctors")]
public class Doctor : User
{
    [Key]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string CurriculumVitae { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I have added the custom index field DoctorId.
But **UserManager can't create the entities** 
So the question is **HOW CAN I ADD THE CUSTOM INT ID INDEX?**

Comment: assuming this is Core - http://ericsmasal.com/2018/05/28/customize-asp-net-cores-identityuser/

Comment: @JohnB, it is better to not to change the base tables

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution!** To force entity to create the key we need to add this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int DoctorId { get; set; }
```

instead of this

```
[Key]
public int DoctorId { get; set; }
```

**But this is NOT the best solution..** Theremore **DON'T INHERIT FROM USER** class to classes wich realize roles!